# combo box and chart visibility (mvvm and wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, charts, combobox

I've got a combo box and a chart to be displayed(Bar) (by mvvm pattern). What i want to do is::

-Loading data from data base into combo box (binding) -(done)

-After loading into combo box, after selecting from combobox, then only the chart will be displayed after selecting combobox value into the query (not done). its not updating on selection change of the combobox

I cannot get the proper flow of this

***viewmodelfile***

```
namespace charting
{
    class fbvm : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public String eID;

        private List<KeyValuePair<string, float>> _chartData;
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, float>> ChartData
        {
            get
            {
                return _chartData;
            }
            set
            {
                _chartData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => ChartData);
            }
        }
        private List<string> _MyComboBoxData;
        public List<string> MyComboBoxData
        {
            get
            {
                return _MyComboBoxData;
            }
            set
            {
                _MyComboBoxData = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => MyComboBoxData);
            }
        }

        private Boolean _loadoncbsel;
        public Boolean loadoncbsel
        {         
            get
            {
                return _loadoncbsel;

            }
            set
            {            
                _loadoncbsel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(() => loadoncbsel);
            }

        }

        private string _selectedcb;
        public string selectedcb
        {
            get
            {

                return _selectedcb;

            }
            set
            {              
                _selectedcb = value;
                 OnPropertyChanged(() => selectedcb);
                 if (value == null)
                     _loadoncbsel = false;
                 else
                     _loadoncbsel = true;
            }

        }

        public fbvm()
        {
            MyComboBoxData = new List<string>();
            comboboxload();
            ChartData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, float>>();

        }

         private void comboboxload()
         {
             OleDbConnection ConDb;

             ConDb = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Admin\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\Feedback\\Feedback.accdb");

             try
             {
                 ConDb.Open();
                 OleDbCommand DBSelect = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select FName, LName,ID_NAME from NameList", ConDb);
                 OleDbDataReader reader = DBSelect.ExecuteReader();
                 while (reader.Read())
                 {
                     string eNAME = "";
                     eID = reader["ID_NAME"].ToString();
                     eNAME += reader["FName"].ToString();
                     eNAME += " " + reader["LName"].ToString();

                     MyComboBoxData.Add(eNAME);
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ae)
             {
                 MessageBox.Show(ae.Message);

             }//catch




         }
        private void LoadColumnChartData()
        {
            int cc1=0,tc1=0,aa1=0,blfe1=0,count=0;
            float cc11 = 0, tc11 = 0, aa11 = 0, blfe11 = 0;
            int year;
            OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Feedback\Feedback.accdb");
            connect.Open();
            string query = "select CC,TC,AA,BLFE,WMU from "+selectedcb;
            OleDbCommand select = new OleDbCommand("select", connect);
            select.CommandText = query;
            OleDbDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                cc1 += Int32.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                tc1 += Int32.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
                aa1 += Int32.Parse(reader[2].ToString());
                blfe1 += Int32.Parse(reader[3].ToString());
                ++count;
            }
            cc11 =(float) cc1 / count; aa11 =(float) aa1 / count;
            tc11 =(float) tc1 / count; blfe11 =(float) blfe1 / count;
         //   cc11 = 3.11f;
         //   MessageBox.Show(cc11.ToString(), tc11.ToString());
            ChartData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("cc", cc11));
            ChartData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("tc", tc11));
            ChartData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("aa", aa11));
            ChartData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, float>("blfe", blfe11));
            ChartData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, float>>(ChartData);

        }//loadcoloumnchart


        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Need to implement this interface in order to get data binding
        /// to work properly.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

    }//class fbvm
}//namespace
```

***xaml file***

```
<Window x:Class="charting.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:DV="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:DVC="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="816.045">
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="btov"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="83*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="434*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
        <Label > Select Name:</Label>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" >
        <ComboBox  x:Name="SelectNameCB"  SelectedValue="{Binding selectedcb, Mode=TwoWay}"  FontSize="15" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" ItemsSource="{Binding MyComboBoxData}" />

        <DVC:Chart Canvas.Top="80" Canvas.Left="10" Name="mcChart"  Margin="10,10,31,0" Height="250" 
       Background="LightGoldenrodYellow"  Title="{Binding Text, ElementName=SelectNameCB}" Visibility="{Binding loadoncbsel, Converter={StaticResource btov}}" >
            <DVC:Chart.Series>
                <DVC:BarSeries   Title="Avg. Score" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChartData}" Margin="10,10,76,10" AnimationSequence="LastToFirst">
                </DVC:BarSeries>

            </DVC:Chart.Series>
        </DVC:Chart>


    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

combo box:
 `<ComboBox  x:Name="SelectNameCB"  FontSize="15" Margin="10,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" ItemsSource="{Binding MyComboBoxData}" SelectedItem="{Binding Indexname, Mode=TwoWay}" />`

`

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind `SelectedItem` property instead of `SelectedValue` :

```
<ComboBox  x:Name="SelectNameCB"  
           SelectedItem="{Binding selectedcb, Mode=TwoWay}"  
           ItemsSource="{Binding MyComboBoxData}" 
           ...... />
```

Then upon `selectedcb` property set, populate the chart by calling `LoadColumnChartData()` :

```
public string selectedcb
{
    get{...}
    set
    {              
        _selectedcb = value;
         OnPropertyChanged(() => selectedcb);
         if (value == null)
             _loadoncbsel = false;
         else
         {
             _loadoncbsel = true;
             LoadColumnChartData();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: "not working" is never enough information to diagnose a problem, let alone to fix it

Comment: sorry @har07 i was working on that...

Its still not showing the chart.
i've check the parameter values.. the _loadoncbsel never getting updated.

Comment: How about the combobox, does it populated properly?

Comment: yes. combo box is populated properly.
i was just checking, its not updating true value for _loadoncbsel

Comment: if you put breakpoint at setter of `selectedcb` does it hit? if yes, does setter of `_loadoncbsel` then called? Any binding error message in output window?

Comment: ALL BREAKPOINTS ARE DONE...!! STILL MAKING A KINDA RESEARCH ON THAT.. BINDING IS DONE PROPER ... CODE IS WORKING IF INITIAL INDEX OF COMBOBOX IS MADE 1 OR MORE..!! AFTER SELECTION THE VALUES ARE NOT GETTING UPDATED IN THE VIEWMODEL FILE TO REFLECT THE XAML FILE..